# Codeigniter mobile redirect with caching

Tags: codeigniter, mobile, user-agent

I have got my site(mysite.com) to redirect to mysite.com/Mobile for mobile browsers using codeigniters useragent library from my default controller.

When I cache my output from the controller the redirect doesnt work as the browser is served the cached file.

Is there a proper way to go about redirecting from the config/routes.php file? Will this redirect mobile visitors?

My controller

class Child extends Controller {

```
function child()
{
    parent::Controller();
    //$this->output->cache(7200);
    $agent = $this->agent->browser() . ' ver ' . $this->agent->version();

}

function index()
{
    if ($this->agent->is_mobile())
    {
        header('Location: ' . site_url() . 'Mobile/', TRUE, 301);
        exit(0); 
    }else{
        $this->output->cache(7200);
        $this->load->view('home',$data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't suggest using CodeIgniter's output caching. That runs before the Controller, therefore you will never get in the `index()`. Routing can't deal with this situation as it isn't able to detect if the client is mobile.

It's a better idea to use the other caching method that CodeIgniter offers, as it's more granular, you can cache the single views. http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/caching.html

```
function index()
{
    // should put this in the __construct() of this controller or in your MY_Controller.php
    $this->load->driver('cache', array('adapter' => 'apc', 'backup' => 'file'));

    if ($this->agent->is_mobile())
    {
        redirect('Mobile');
    }
    else
    {
        // if this doesn't get us the output, recreate and store it
        if(!$output = $this->cache->get('controllername_index_output'))
        {
            $output = $this->load->view('home', $data, TRUE);
            $this->cache->save('controllername_index_output', $output, 7200);
        }

        // now we surely have the output ready, whether it was cached or not
        $this->output->set_output($output);         
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It makes perfect sense. I am still running CI version 1.7. I cannot see the cache drivers under libraries. Does caching not work the same way in CI 1.7?

Comment: This other kind of caching was implemented in 2.0. You will need to manually use APC/memcached to use the caching as you need it. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apc-add.php in example is little different to use than the CodeIgniter function.